# Repeating month names for the X axis of the Shield UI Chart

Tags: javascript, shieldui

I came across the following problem trying the Shield UI Chart. I specified 3 month names for the chart, using the following code:

```
axisX:{
 categoricalValues: ['January','February','March']
},
```

However I added some more points and after the last month there showed numbers on the axis. Why is that? Isn't this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The categoricalValues property is used for showing categories and the corresponding values for each category. Although using months looks a little bit confusing. 
Nevertheless once there is a category placed on the X axis, there is no logical reason for that category to reappear after the list of categories has been used. And the reason is quite simple- if there is a category A, appearing again will make no sence, since we already have it.